# Why doesn't knitr respect RStudio project details?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

In all other cases, when I am working within an RStudio project, I can make references relative to the project root in scripts. So I can, for example, `dfX = read.csv("Data/somefile.csv")`, where the folder `Data` is relative to my project root.

The same code in a `knitr` chunk does not find the file. I guess this is because `knitr` creates a bunch of temporary directories that it needs to refer to relative to the file location. Is there an easy way to change this behavior? Obviously, I would not like to add the entire path to the project folder -- I am aware that I can easily do this using `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rootPath)`. That completely breaks maintainability across machines and OSs.

---

**Edit:** This seems closely linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890190/address-project-root-in-rstudio).

Comment: why not use `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = getwd())`?

Comment: @Jthorpe That won't work, because `getwd()` would return the RMarkdown document directory.

Comment: @Jthorpe You can test this by compiling the Rmarkdown `\`\`\` {r}
print(getwd())
\`\`\``.

Comment: Ok, Good to know.  This may not be a solution to your problem, but if you are trying to import a dataset that is stored in your `/data` directory, you can save it as an .Rda file in your data directory (e.g. `save(mydata=mydata,file='path/to/myPackage/data/mydata.Rda')`) and in your .Rmd file, you can call `data(myData)` to read in the stored data.  [Of course you would have to call `library(myPackage)` before calling `data()`...]

Comment: @Jthorpe No, too complicated, and not just for data either. I was hoping that the `rstudioapi` provided a function to return the project directory, but doesn't appear to be one...

Comment: what are you trying to store besides data?  functions?

Comment: @Jthorpe Whatever, right? -- scripts, data, save out graphs...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know the path to the package directory when you call 'knit', so how about:

```
ENV <- new.env()
assign("workingDirectory", getcwd(), envir = ENV)
knitr::knit(...,
            # THE ENVIRONMENT IN WHICH THE CODE CHUNKS ARE TO BE EVALUATED
            envir=ENV)
```

Then in your rmd file you can do:

````
```{r]  print(workingDirectory)```
````

If you're searching for the location of the current install, you can use:

```
PATH = NULL
for(libPath in .libPaths())
    if('myPackage' %in% list.dirs(libPath,FALSE,FALSE)){
        PATH = file.path(libPath,'myPackage')
    }

if(is.null(PATH))
    stop('could not find package directory') 

ENV <- new.env()
assign("workingDirectory", PATH, envir = ENV)
knitr::knit(...,
            # THE ENVIRONMENT IN WHICH THE CODE CHUNKS ARE TO BE EVALUATED
            envir=ENV)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this does not work across machines.

Comment: It will work on any one given machine, but the same code is not portable across machines.

Comment: Oh, yes, A literal string with the package directory won't work across machines but `assign("workingDirectory", getcwd(), envir = ENV)` will. See edits

Comment: That is not my workflow for `knit`ting documents. I use the IDE shortcut `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the document that you are "knitting" is in a subdirectory itself. It seems that, when you click "Knit PDF", RStudio or `knitr` will `setwd()` to the directory containing the file being knitted. So you may need to do something like `dfX = read.csv("../Data/somefile.csv")` to get the reference right.

I have a working example [here](https://github.com/iangow/knitr_grandchildren).