# How can/should I set my path.expand in RStudio per project?

Tags: r, rstudio

My goal is to have `path.expand` to be automatically modified as I open a project, so that I don't have to keep writing `fread(paste0(getwd(),"foo.csv")` every time I load a new file, replacing it instead with `fread("~.foo.csv")`

I've found this question: [address project root in Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890190/address-project-root-in-rstudio)

Which seems to suggest that there is a `.R_USER` file per project in Rstudio. I have successfully been running an R studio project in a folder, and have 'unhidden' the the `.Rproj_user` folder, however, I am now at a loss to edit it. I'm seeing a tonne of different folders and don't really understand what I can edit, or how.

Is this the right `path` to `expand` upon? (jks), or is there a simpler and different way to do this? Is this even sensible? It seems like it is to me, but I'm new to all this, so please do say if this is stupid (and why).

Comment: When I open a new project, the working directory is set where the project file is located. Using "file.csv" works out of the box, provided the file is in the same folder. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the working directory is indeed, and when queried does change as new projects are loaded. My problem is that tilde expansion and `path.expand` are still referring to my main `C:/user/docs` folder, even when I'm in a project. i.e. `path.expand("~/foo.csv")`

Comment: I think tilde represents the home directory on some systems. If you want the "current point", try `.`, i.e. `./foo.csv`.

Comment: Just noticed this is still open. I've adopted the "./folder/file.type" syntax in conjunction with using rstudio projects. If you want to provide your comment as an answer @RomanLuštrik I'll be happy to accept.